# How to make mesh grow to create form

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, shape-keys, path, lattice

I would like my mesh to grow to form this logo:
[image: logo]

I created a curve and made the mesh grow along it. The problem in with the 45º edges. See here better:

[image: mesh growing along curve]

Any hints please?

Edit:

I have tried using a Lattice but it is so difficult to model it. Is there a way to extrude a lattice?

[image: Trying to model a lattice]

Check out the kind of animation I need:
[image: animation example]

Answer (score 1):

Your idea with the curve isn't bad at all, but for the form of the log you need to alter the geometry as well, I would suggest, create the logo as one mesh, create the shape as simple as possible, in this case just use a plane create the outline, cut the angles with the knife-tool and keep it with only quads, it should be very easy to create this mesh ;-)
When you have the finished mesh, create a few shape-keys, where you just move the vertices back to where they should start. Then insert Keyframes to your timeline, to control the different shape-keys. All the best Marco

For a better understanding here is a quick example of how I would do it.
Here is a little Video https://youtu.be/OW1WdF42yrk on how it would work. And here is a dropboxlink to the example file https://www.dropbox.com/s/aas26i1z0t2e5wa/Logo_folded.blend?dl=0

All the best Marco

Comment: Hey @marco, don't think I understood what you mean.

Comment: @FaridAbdelnour I created a littel example, so it's clearer what I mean. Just a quick example, without the right size, of your Logo, and you can definately add more steps in between, but it will work as a proof of concept. All the best Marco

Comment: Thanks for the hwlp :)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it works for you.

Comment: Hi, me again, sorry to bother you, but it is not working exactly as i needed. Have a look at the blend file to see the kind of animation I would like it to do.