# Is there a way to convert a Mesh into a Lattice?

Tags: mesh, lattice

I want to do this to control the flow of another mesh. The problem is that it is very difficult to model a lattice. I wish we had a way to extrude the points.

Comment: Does the mesh deform modifier work for your case, or do you need a lattice specifically?

Comment: What I would like to do is to use the mesh as a path to guide another mesh. Think of it as a fluid simulation.

Comment: @Brenticus I am trying to find a workaround for this issue I am having: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173208/how-to-make-mesh-grow-to-create-form 

So that is why maybe a lattice approach could fix it, But it is so difficult to modify/shape a lattice.